# CSS styling, 100%/100vh wont cover pass view height

Tags: css, flexbox

On the bottom of the image below, the background-color doesn't reach all the way. I've tried setting it to `100vh and 100%` but the outcomes are the same where it only covers up to a 100 view height, and anything scrolled pass down the 100vh. isnt covered by my background color. How can i fix this?

```
    &__container {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: rgba($color: #13182c, $alpha: 0.7);
        height: 100vh;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `position: fixed;` on the container so it won't scroll with the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should post your full code.

But your posted image looks like that page is scrolled down a bit (the nav items behind the overlay are cut off). You are using `position: absolute`, which moves along with the next higher relatively positioned element, or - if there is none - with the `body`. This would explain the problem. Body is scrolled , overlay moves along, but is only as high as the window, but since the body is higher, there's some space below the overlay...

To fix that, try to use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`. In that case the overlay position will relate to the viewport itself (i.e. the window).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `position: relative`, once you want full cover. Also you can can set `background-size = cover`. Just tweak width.